# How do I call now() of SQL through a Groovy sql string?

Tags: mysql, groovy

I am trying to run an insert using executeInsert of Groovy using a prepared sql statement with paramteres. One of the columns is a datetime column and I want to call now() of MySql. However I get an error of incompatible types, I am assuming because it treats now as a string. How do I call it using a statement?

```
String sql = """
INSERT INTO table
VALUES (:id, :datetime)
"""

sql.executeInsert(sql, [id: 0, datetime:"now()"])
```

Comment: `dateTime: new Date()` or put now() in the string if they're all now

Comment: How does this compile? You have a string sql, and then run `sql.executeInsert(...)`? 

Also, there is a typo in INSERT

Comment: I am just roughing an approximation, a segment of the code. It compiles

Comment: @tim_yates They are not all now, I have to parameterize it

Answer (score 0):

Either give in the datetime by calculating the current time in Groovy already, or use two different sql Strings, one with hard-coded `now()` in it, the other with parameter you set. I don't think you can give the db-function `now()` as parameter to a prepared statement, just actual values.